# Question about translation with particle ほど

Tags: translation

Help me please with translating this sentence -

> 「ああいう奴らの家庭ほど、家に帰るとぐちゃぐちゃだったりすんのよ」

Maybe I’m missing something, but that part just does’t make much sense to me. My interpritation would sound some thing like this – 方２ says that she getting irrated from these guys so much, that when she comes home she is a mess, just like those guys parents which are always with them, so the translation would sound something like this –

> “To the extent of their family(just like their family), when I come
> home I’m a mess.”

But I’m having some doubts with this translation, so I would really appreciate your help.

> 方１：「ほんとうのことです。学校でも家でもいつもひとりで、給食の時間とか運動会とか文化祭とか、みんなが楽しそうに盛り上がる時間が大嫌いでした」
>
> 方２：「わ、あたしと同じだ。あたしもああいうの大っ嫌い」
>
> 方２：「なんかみんなベタベタして仲良し比べみたいな感じでさ。ああいう奴らの家庭ほど、家に帰るとぐちゃぐちゃだったりすんのよ」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will be honest but please do not feel discouraged.  Hopefully, you can learn something from your mistakes.　A spoken line by a teenager would not be the easiest thing for a language learner to handle.

Your translation:

> “To the extent of their family(just like their family), when I come home I’m a mess.”

is not even close to the original:

> 「ああいう[奴]{やつ}らの[家庭]{かてい}ほど、[家]{うち}に[帰]{かえ}るとぐちゃぐちゃだったりすんのよ。」

Where do you get the first-person pronoun "I" from?  The sentence is NOT about the speaker (方2).  It is about the families of those students that both 方1 and 方2 hate so much from school.

ああいう奴ら = "guys like that", "those types", etc. (whom 方1 and 方2 dislike).

The subject of the predicate 「ぐちゃぐちゃだったりすんのよ」 is 「ああいう奴らの家庭」.

The 「ほど」 expresses "inverse proportion" here.  The guys that 方1 and 方2 dislike so much are the happy guys at school, right?  They are the ones that have a great time at school.  方2 is saying that the happier kids are at school, the more ぐちゃぐちゃ (= "f***ed-up") their families would tend to be.

My own TL attempt: "It is the families of those types that are likely to be f***ed-up (when they go home)."